# how to generate a random number within a range given the probability of getting one of the numbers

Tags: c

i am trying to generate a random number within a range from -1 to 6, but for every time I generate a random number the probability of getting a number in the range is given by a percentage. For example, in a list of percentages, the first percentage has the probability of generating a 6, the second percentage has the probability of generating a 5, and so on. The numbers must must be generated randomly. I am trying to code this in C. Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: To the VTC-ers. This is actually a quite common thing (the opposite of too localised), although it is described in a bit of a convoluted manner.

Answer (score 4):

You could get a random number between 0 and 100 and check what percentage range that falls in and assign the corresponding value to it.

For example:

```
    0 - 5  : -1
    5 - 25 :  0
    25 - 31:  1
    31 - 48:  2
    48 - 50:  3
    50 - 75:  4
    75 - 87:  5
    87 - 100: 6
```

**EDIT:**

To implement this you would need one or two arrays, one that stores the percentage boundaries (meaning 5, 25, 31, 48, 50, 75, 87 in this case) and another array that stores the output values (if the outputs are completely random, here where they are sequential you wouldn't need a second array).
Then you get call `rand() * 100.0 / RAND_MAX` to get a random float between 0 and 100 or `rand() % 100 + 1` for a random int between 0 and 100.

With this you can use a binary search method to find what percentage range this corresponds to in O(log n) time.  With the index you find the corresponding output (either via an array or a function)

Comment: I actually did something like this but i taught i was doing it wrong..but thanks for clarifying it for me

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework assignment?  I'm going to assume not, for the sake of having faith in humanity ;)

So I mean, all your percentages should add up to 100 right?
You could generate a number between 0 and 100, and see which bracket it falls into.

i.e. If your percentages are [10,20,35,15,10,10]

Then the first bracket is "< 10" so any number generated under 10 yeilds a 6

```
x < 10 --> 6
10 <= x < (10+20) --> 5
(10+20) <= x < (10+20+35) --> 4
(10+20+35) <= x < (10+20+35+15) --> 3
```

etc.  You'd want to generate a random float between 1 and 100 to satisfy precice percentages like 11.9 for instance.

Comment: no its not a home work assignment ;) I was just try to make a simple text based game. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

Make an array to have 100 elements, fill it with -1 to 6, depends on how much weight each needs. for example, if you need -1 to have 15% hit, you fill 15 elements with -1.
now generate a random number from 1 to 100, and simply look up the array, you get the actual results weighted.

Comment: since he is doing a text base game, I think integer percentage suffice, unless he says otherwise. This should also give good performance for high frequency use.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't mean your method was invalid, just that there is a caveat

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other, probably better, ways of doing this, but what comes to mind is this: Create an array containing appropriate copies of each number (-1 to 6) according to your percentages. Then randomly pick an element in the array.

Comment: This works if the percentages are integers, for percentages like 0.5% this wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do that is to consider the following analogy:

If you have a line [0,1], you can think that generating a number from 1 to 4 is equivalent to split the line in 4 segments, S_1 = [0,1/4], S_2 = [1/4,2/4], S_3 = [2/4,3/4], S_4 = [3/4,1]. That way, when you generate a number from [0,1], if it falls on the segment S_i, the generated number is i.

If you want to assign different probabilities to each number, say p_i, them you just have to divide the segment in different sizes, according with p_i.

For example, for 1 with p_1 = 0.1, 2 with p_2 = 0.4, 3 with p_3 = 0.2 and 4 with p_4 = 0.3 you can use the segments S_1 = [0,p_1], S_2 = [p_1,p_1+p_2], S_3 = [p_1+p_2,p_1+p_2+p_3] and S_4 = [p_1+p_2+p_3,p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4]

Then you generate a uniform random number on [0,1], and test whether it fell in S_i.

Comment: You have a good point.  This is very similar to my solution, but the range could actually by any range you want to use I suppose, as long as the ratios are correct.  Setting ranges between 0 and 1 is nice if your percentages and random number generator are already in that range.